# Changing Project Build Configuration in Bulk VS6

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-6

Does anybody know if it is possible to change the build configuration settings on a group of VS6 project files?

I'm working on a very large project which is still using Visual Studio 6 (I know) and the default build config is set to either `Win32 DebugOCI` or `Win32 ReleaseOCI` depending on the project.

I'm looking to change it to `Win32 Debug` across the board for consistency, and as a QoL improvement, rather than forget to check each time I make a different project active within the workspace.

Is there a way to do this for all of the projects within a workspace at once? Really not a fan of the idea of doing it manually for all ~475 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio allows you to write '**User Defined Macros**'

Menu option :`Visual Studio -> Tools -> Macros`

[image]

Macro would look something like this. Note: This is rough work.

```
Sub SetDefaultConfigurationMacro()
    ' Get all projects in the workspace
    Set ProjectsCols = Application.Projects
    for each Proj in ProjectsCols
       if Proj.Type = "Build" then
          Set ConfigCols = Proj.Configurations          
          for each Config in ConfigCols
             if InStr( Config.Name, "Debug" ) > 0 then
               Config.MakeCurrentSettingsDefault
             end if
          Next ' For 
       end if
    Next ' For 
End Sub
```

You will find entire set of Methods, Objects, Properties & Events supported by Visual Studio Developer Objects. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232397(v=vs.60).aspx)